# Mitigating markdown's XSS vulnerability w/o converting it to HTML

Tags: node.js

After reading [this guide](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown/wiki/Markdown's-XSS-Vulnerability-(and-how-to-mitigate-it)) on how to mitigate markdown's XSS vulnerability. I've been struggling to find the right way for my scenario. Specifically with one of the points discussed in the guide: the best way to find out if markdown contains any XSS attempt is to first convert it to and check the HTML.

Let's say i am building a book/story publishing platform. So i don't need links or images in my markdown.

I came up with the following steps:

--- Client side ---

1. User Imports .docs, .odt or .txt file.
2. File is converted to markdown (using mammoth in the case of .docs).
3. User is presented with an editor to format/edit his text before submitting. (submit to server)

--- Server side ---

4. Markdown is verified and converted to HTML then checked for XSS attempts.
5. If the markdown is valid it's stored in the DB. If not the user receives an error (maybe something more consequential).

The thing I find kinda hacky is point 4 where i have to convert markdown to HTML just to check for attempts.

So my question is if anybody knows of better ways. Maybe to directly sanitize markdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Writing a Markdown Parser**

If you are willing to write a markdown parser that can identify embedded html you can of course directly analyse the markdown for xss vulnerabilities.

The problem is that your markdown parser will need to know how this will be converted into html so that it can identify any interplay between the tags it generates and the embedded tags.

Assuming you achieve this, you are still not sure if you have caught everything - particularly when you update the html generator.

**Testing the conversion**

Converting the markdown to html using the converter will give you guaranteed output, and better yet no guessing required.

Another perk is that you can use exploit analysis tools from the much larger, broader, and mature web community. The same community who are defending against these exploits and most likely to know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making a capital mistake here. XSS is not prevented through validation but through proper output escaping. Also don't gloss over Self-XSS.

I suggest the following:

Cleint side:

1. Check for banned elements and warn the user, that they are not supported (images and links)

Server side when saving: nothing, just save

Server side when sending out HTML for anyone to view: keep a whitelist of tags and attributes to allow. Remove everything else from the final HTML.

---

As to the preview while editing: generate the HTML for the preview on the server,using the same whitelist. Otherwise you've got a Self-XSS vector.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i did plan on also escaping the html. This post was more focused on detecting malicous intent server-side before any users are requesting it. Maybe to enforce some kind of consequence for the user submiting it. Even if it's escaped on the client side.

Comment: Why do you want to enforce consequences? IMHO you risk f*ing off legitimate users and/or allow for a self-DOS (like self-XSS). Isn't wasting time on your software punishment enough for the bad guys?